# Application Launcher Text - Application Name in two lines

Tags: android, android-widget

Currently i am developing **an application whose name is long , so i would like to display name in two line same** as **"Quick Calendar"** and **"Search People"** in an attached home screen widget:

Please show me a way to implement this ?? is it possible to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `\\n` for a newline character.

Comment: thanx for the support, but where do i written \\n ?? should i written it into the AndroidManifest.xml file, i have written the app name as android:label="@string/app_name" in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani: "but where do i written \\n ??" -- wherever you need it. In your case, you should have a `res/values/strings.xml` file for that string resource you are using in the manifest. If nothing else, use the advanced tools known as "search" or "`grep`" to find where the words are in the files in your project directory.

Comment: ok i changed the "app_name" string inside the strings.xml as "demo\nApplication" and then that string i have used insdie the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: After changing as above, its working SUCCESSFULLY. Found Really really helpful

Comment: not working for me, I just see "first\nsecond" with the slash n. any idea?

Comment: It only works in Emulator '\n' and shows invalid icon error while uploading to market.

Comment: @CommonsWare \\n doesn't work for me shows up as 'MyApp\nName' from strings.xml as `<string name="app_name">MyApp\nName</string> `.  I think it's getting cut at 11th character . any idea ?

Comment: @Annu: No, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\n \r` but remember to enclose the string in quotes `"... \n ... "`

Answer (score 0):

use XML escape for new line  " `&#10;`" this will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">"namr &#10; namr"</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: How did you get this to work? It still is showing as Normal with Ellipses for me