# Making Double Line for Android Apps Icon

Tags: android, android-studio

Has anyone come across this request for feature on Android Development.  I'm currently using Android Studio and when I'm testing the apps using the AVD, I'd like the label on my icon launcher to be double line rather than single line.

[image: Sample Icons]

I've played around the app_name strings variable by changing it to different format and no luck.

First question, is it doable?

Second question, if yes, how?

Please help?  Many thanks.

Comment: I tried this suggestion:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345920/application-launcher-text-application-name-in-two-lines

not taking the \\n  I typed "My \\nApps" and nothing other than it shown as "My \nApps".  Strange..  Help?

Answer (score 1):

step-1 >>Go to String.xml and find your app name tag

step-2 >>Break your app name using "\n" from the place where you want

Comment: Thanks @Dhaval.  I did that already.  It still shown as one line.  Here is my string.      <string name="app_name">My\nApp</string> and it shown as "My App" .  Any other suggestion?